# Firebase: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

After I just started the app, I am not logged in, I try to read a document by id:

```
static async getUserByUID(uid) {

        let ref = firebase.firestore().collection("users");
        let user = await ref.doc(uid).get()
        
        return user
        
}
```

And I get an error:

```
Missing or insufficient permissions.
* http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:184506:21 in e
- node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:1:23672 in t.prototype.Vt
- node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:1:31796 in t.ee
- node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:1:148981 in <global>
- node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:1:48518 in e
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:458:30 in callImmediates
* [native code]:null in callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:407:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:143:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:142:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

My rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

If I open all permissions all works fine, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules require the user to be signed in (with Firebase Authentication) in order to access data. The error message indicates that the user is not signed in, when they're trying to load the data.

The solution is to sign the user in with Firebase Authentication before loading data. For example:

```
await auth().signInAnonymously()
let ref = firebase.firestore().collection("users");
let user = await ref.doc(uid).get()
```

---

From your comments you seem confused about the rules language. To allow reads to anyone, and only allow writes for users that are authentication, you'd do:

```
allow read: if true;
allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
```

Comment: but read is allowed, only write requires authentication, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, that's not what your rules currently do. I added an explanation of that to my answer.